# Using Neo4j fulltext indexing for Contains queries

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher

I'm using neo4j 3.5, and have about 9 million user nodes. I was trying to implement the following query, but it was taking way too long:

> MATCH (users:`User`) WHERE (users.username CONTAINS "joe" OR users.first_name CONTAINS "joe" OR users.last_name CONTAINS "joe") 
>   RETURN users
>   LIMIT 30

I was hoping to take advantage of neo4j 3.5's newe fulltext indexing feature by creating the following index:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('users', ['User'], ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
```

and then querying the db like so

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('users', joe)
YIELD node
RETURN node.user_id
```

I thought this would work the same as contains and return users whose username, first_name or last_name contains joe (eg: myjoe12, joe12, 12joe, 44joeseph, etc.) but it seems to be returning users whose fields are `joe` exactly or contain `joe` separated by a whitespace (eg: Joe B, Joe y1), I tried using `joe*` in the query but that only returns everything starting with `joe`, I want to return everything containing `joe` or whatever search term. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

### Speed issue / Index:

So far I know, Neo4j has a optimised index for `STARTS WITH` & `ENDS WITH` only for NOT composite indexes.

If I read this [docs paragraph](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/#schema-index-substring-search-using-contains-single-property-index), my conclusion will be this: Your 9 million users will be searched one by one, neo4j doesn't use any index for your query. What makes this query really slow.

### A answer to your question:

> I want to return everything containing `Joe` or whatever search term.

You probably looking for a regex search (this is also slow and not a index search and not recommended):

Example query based on your query:

```
MATCH (users:User)
WHERE (users.username =~ "(?i).*joe.*" OR users.first_name =~ "(?i).*joe.*" OR users.last_name =~ "(?i).*joe.*")
RETURN users
LIMIT 30
```

Explanation for `(?i)` this means case-insensitive so `Joe` or `joe` will be matched. See [regex operator docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-a-regular-expression-to-filter-words) and [regex where docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/clauses/where/#query-where-regex)

Answer (score 0):

For the fulltext schema index, it looks like you'll need to use the fuzzy search operator `~` in your query, though you may need to do some filtering on the score to make sure you're looking at relevant results:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('users', 'joe~')
YIELD node, score
WHERE score > .8
RETURN node.user_id
```